# Changing the opacity of mask behind the modal window extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I want to change the opacity of mask behind the modal window. I want to make it opaque. And this is to be donw only for one window. Can someone tell me how I can do it? 
I tried

```
    this.getEl().setOpacity(1);
    this.mask.setStyle('opacity', 1);
    this.el.mask().setStyle('opacity',1);
```

I tried these three codes but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had similar requirement, used domQuery to get 'x-mask' el and added css to change the opacity.

eg., window's on show..

```
show: function(win) {
            if (this.modal) {
                var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');
                var el = Ext.get(dom[0]);
                el.addCls('customWinMask'); //remove on hide
            }
}
```

CSS:

```
.customWinMask.x-mask {
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        opacity: .5;
        background: blue !important; 
}
```

working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7fu

Comment: Hey Thank you :) It worked for me but I had to get the sixth elemnt of dom,      var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');               var el = Ext.get(dom[6]);                el.setStyle('opacity',1);

Comment: hey so I used the above code, but for the window there is again a confirmation window coming up, so what happens is when confirmation window is shown, the previous window gets hidden behind the mask, the ideal scenario is we should be able to see the confirmation windowand the previous window both, but when we press yes on confirmation window, it should close the previous window and we should be able to remove the mask.

Answer (score 1):

So, the above code dint work for me completely. I had to use the followinf modification to it,

```
 show: function(win) {
           if (this.modal) {
                     var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');
                     for(var i=0; i<dom.length;i++){
                         Ext.get(dom[i]).setStyle('opacity',1);
                     }
           }
},


 close:  function(win) {
                 if (this.modal) {
                     var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');
                     for(var i=0; i<dom.length;i++){
                         Ext.get(dom[i]).setStyle('opacity',0);
                     }
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user2316489, you should change opacity from 1 to 0.5 for example:

this.getEl().setOpacity(0.5);
this.el.mask().setStyle('opacity',0.5);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sass variables for Ext.LoadMask, for example:

```
$loadmask-opacity:0.3;
$loadmask-page-opacity:$loadmask-opacity;
```

Rules on ExtJs v6.0

Answer (score 0):

Go to sass > etc > all.scss and put this code:

```
.x-mask {
    opacity : 0.3
}
```

It worsk perfecty in extjs 6.0